# Android backstack like instagram

Tags: android, android-navigation

Short and simple version: I am trying to achieve a backstack just like the app Instagram.

**How their navigation work**

In instagram they use navigation from a bottombar. Without knowing how the code looks like. They create some kind of 4 lane backstack.

So lets say i click on Home (lane 1). I then manage to click on a post -> click on a user -> click on another post -> and lastly click on a hashtag

I have then added 4 pages to the backstack for that lane.

I then do something similar to another lane (lets say the account page).

I know have 2 lanes with 4 pages in both. If i would hit back button at this point. I would just traverse back at the same pages as i opened them.

But if i instead clicked back to Home (from the bottom navigation) and clicked backbutton from there. I would traverse back from lane 1 instead of lane 2.

**The big question**

How can i achieve this lane like backstacking? is there a simple way im not thinking of?

**What i managed to do so far**

I have not managed to do a lot. I created a test project where i experiment with this type of navigation. What i managed to do so far is to create one massive backstack of all my bottombar navigation pages

My guess on how i would achieve this kind of feature is to move some parts of the backstack to the top and move the other back. But How is that possible?

Comment: I'm on mobile so can't answer now but you can use a FragmentManager in each of the pages with its own back stack and override the main activity's onBackPressed to call the active FragmentManager's popBackStack method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue i was having. Dont give me full credit. I had a reference code that i looked at. Please check below.

This is maybe not a solid solution. But it may help you understand the logic behind how it works. So you can create your own solution that fits your needs.

Hope this helps :)

**Background how my app works**

To start with. I just want to let you all know how my app works. So you know why i chose my route of implementing this navigation. I have an activity that keeps the references to all the root fragments that it is using. The activity only adds one root fragment at a time. Depending on what button the user clicks.

When the activity creates a new root fragment. It will push it to the managing class that handles it.

The activity itself overrides `onBackPressed()` and calls the made up backstacks `onBackpressed()` function.

The activity will also pass a listener to the managing class. This listener will tell the activity when to shut down the app. And also when to refresh the current active fragment

**BackStackManager.java**

This is the managing class. It keeps a reference to all the different backstacks. It also delegates any fragment transactional duties to its FragmentManager class.

```
public class BackStackManager {

    //region Members
    /** Reference to the made up backstack */
    private final LinkedList<BackStack> mBackStacks;
    /** Reference to listener */
    private final BackStackHelperListener mListener;
    /** Reference to internal fragment manager */
    private final BackStackFragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    //endregion


    //region Constructors
    public BackStackManager(@NonNull final BackStackHelperListener listener,
                            @NonNull final FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        mBackStacks = new LinkedList<>();
        mListener = listener;
        mFragmentManager = new BackStackFragmentManager(fragmentManager);
    }
    //endregion


    //region Methods


    /** When adding a new root fragment
     * IMPORTANT: Activity his holding the reference to the root. */
    public void addRootFragment(@NonNull final Fragment fragment,
                                final int layoutId) {
        if (!isAdded(fragment)) {
            addRoot(fragment, layoutId);
        }
        else if (isAdded(fragment) && isCurrent(fragment)) {
            refreshCurrentRoot();
        }
        else {
            switchRoot(fragment);
            mFragmentManager.switchFragment(fragment);
        }
    }

    /** When activity is calling onBackPressed */
    public void onBackPressed() {
        final BackStack current = mBackStacks.peekLast();
        final String uuid = current.pop();

        if (uuid == null) {
            removeRoot(current);
        }
        else {
            mFragmentManager.popBackStack(uuid);
        }
    }

    /** Adding child fragment */
    public void addChildFragment(@NonNull final Fragment fragment,
                                 final int layoutId) {

        final String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        final BackStack backStack = mBackStacks.peekLast();

        backStack.push(uuid);

        mFragmentManager.addChildFragment(fragment, layoutId, uuid);
    }

    /** Remove root */
    private void removeRoot(@NonNull final BackStack backStack) {
        mBackStacks.remove(backStack);


        //After removing. Call close app listener if the backstack is empty
        if (mBackStacks.isEmpty()) {
            mListener.closeApp();
        }
        //Change root since the old one is out
        else {
            BackStack newRoot = mBackStacks.peekLast();
            mFragmentManager.switchFragment(newRoot.mRootFragment);
        }
    }

    /** Adding root fragment */
    private void addRoot(@NonNull final Fragment fragment, final int layoutId) {

        mFragmentManager.addFragment(fragment, layoutId);

        //Create a new backstack and add it to the list
        final BackStack backStack = new BackStack(fragment);
        mBackStacks.offerLast(backStack);
    }

    /** Switch root internally in the made up backstack */
    private void switchRoot(@NonNull final Fragment fragment) {

        for (int i = 0; i < mBackStacks.size(); i++) {
            BackStack backStack = mBackStacks.get(i);
            if (backStack.mRootFragment == fragment) {
                mBackStacks.remove(i);
                mBackStacks.offerLast(backStack);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /** Let listener know to call refresh */
    private void refreshCurrentRoot() {
        mListener.refresh();
    }

    /** Convenience method */
    private boolean isAdded(@NonNull final Fragment fragment) {
        for (BackStack backStack : mBackStacks) {
            if (backStack.mRootFragment == fragment) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /** Convenience method */
    private boolean isCurrent(@NonNull final Fragment fragment) {
        final BackStack backStack = mBackStacks.peekLast();
        return backStack.mRootFragment == fragment;
    }

    //endregion
}
```

**BackStackFragmentManager.java**

This class handles all fragment transactions. such as adding/removing/hiding/showing. This class lives within the BackStackManager class.

```
public class BackStackFragmentManager {

    //region Members
    /** Reference to fragment manager */
    private final FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    /** Last added fragment */
    private Fragment mLastAdded;
    //endregion


    //region Constructors
    public BackStackFragmentManager(@NonNull final FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        mFragmentManager = fragmentManager;
    }
    //endregion


    //region Methods

    /** Switch root fragment */
    public void switchFragment(@NonNull final Fragment fragment) {
        final FragmentTransaction transaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        transaction.show(fragment);
        transaction.hide(mLastAdded);

        transaction.commit();

        mLastAdded = fragment;
    }

    /** Adding child fragment to a root */
    public void addChildFragment(@NonNull final Fragment fragment,
                                 final int layoutId,
                                 @NonNull final String tag) {


        final FragmentTransaction transaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(layoutId, fragment, tag);
        transaction.commit();
    }


    /** Add a root fragment */
    public void addFragment(@NonNull Fragment fragment, int layoutId) {
        final FragmentTransaction transaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        //since we hide/show. This should only happen initially
        if (!fragment.isAdded()) {
            transaction.add(layoutId, fragment, fragment.getClass().getName());
        }
        else {
            transaction.show(fragment);
        }

        if (mLastAdded != null) {
            transaction.hide(mLastAdded);
        }

        transaction.commit();

        mLastAdded = fragment;
    }

    /** Pop back stack
     * Function is removing childs that is not used!
     */
    public void popBackStack(@NonNull final String tag) {
        final Fragment fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
        final FragmentTransaction transaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.remove(fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    //endregion
}
```

**BackStack.java**

This is a simple class that just handles internal references to the root and tags to all the backstack child entries. And also handling of these child entries

```
public class BackStack {

    //region Members
    public final Fragment mRootFragment;
    final LinkedList<String> mStackItems;
    //endregion


    //region Constructors
    public BackStack(@NonNull final Fragment rootFragment) {
        mRootFragment = rootFragment;
        mStackItems = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    //endregion


    //region Methods
    public String pop() {
        if (isEmpty()) return null;
        return mStackItems.pop();
    }

    public void push(@NonNull final String id) {
        mStackItems.push(id);
    }


    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return mStackItems.isEmpty();
    }
    //endregion
}
```

**Listener**

Not much to say about this. It is implemented by the activity

```
public interface BackStackHelperListener {
    /** Let the listener know that the app should close. The backstack is depleted */
    void closeApp();

    /** Let the listener know that the user clicked on an already main root. So app can do
     * a secondary action if needed
     */
    void refresh();

}
```

**References**

https://blog.f22labs.com/instagram-like-bottom-tab-fragment-transaction-android-389976fb8759